# Series about a girl who is taken in by a witch, and a vampire family that have big dogs

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

The book is about this girl who is taken in by a witch, and a vampire family that have big dogs. She starts to travel to another parallel Earth in her dreams, caused by the witch. The girl goes to an Earth with no humans and only vampires where she meets a group of them. The witch protects her when she goes. After a while of traveling back and forth she gets caught and is forced to transport a group of vampires back to her world, they have to touch this statue to cross over. While the girl is in the other Earth the witch protects her by not allowing the vampires to smell her blood so when they travel back to her original Earth the boy vampire she loves smells her blood.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the name of any of the characters or locations?  Any idea what the cover art was?

Comment: i remember the beginning the witch and her lover were in the victorian era and they were looking out the window and the man was looking down at the people walking around the carriages and silently wished they got hit. later she is trying to revive him by using the girl somehow? her lover is in the house in a vampire sleep in a hidden room

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Comment: You8 mention it is a book series. Roughly how many books, and how thick were they?

Comment: i read this series probably 5 years ago, and there are 3-4 books in the series. it might have a dark rose or vampire cover, i read it through apple books